How do I retrieve the IP of the frontend that is making the API call in ASP .NET Core?
I want to implement some security so only local connections can make calls to my ASP .NET Core Web API. Therefor I first looked at IsLocal but I had an issue where it couldn't be found. So I now use this code to check if the incoming request is from the local IP or not.
var connection = req.HttpContext.Connection;
Console.WriteLine(connection.RemoteIpAddress);
Console.WriteLine(connection.LocalIpAddress);
if (connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
{
    if (connection.LocalIpAddress != null)
    {
        return connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(connection.LocalIpAddress);
    }
    else
    {
        return IPAddress.IsLoopback(connection.RemoteIpAddress);
    }
}

The issue is that it takes the IP of the device that is accessing the web app (Vue) instead of the IP of the frontend itself. For example the front and backend run on the same NAS with IP 1.1.1.10 and someone with ip 1.1.1.20 accesses the frontend, the RemoteIpAdress is the .20 and not the .10 of the frontend. This seems logical but is not what I need. I'm not sure if the Vue code can be altered to achieve this but my request looks like this.
let result = await axios.post(url, formData)


Edit cleared it up a bit ... I am thinking you may want to look into client authentication and/or CORS.

@Fildor I am planning on adding those as well, but this would have made it a bit easier since the authentication i have to work with is the Synology API. And if I ever made an endpoint and forgot some config it would have been "closed" to the outside by default.

So, basically you want to make sure the request is issued by means of the client app served by your network (the host on 1.1.1.10 in your example) but the client using that app doesn't have to be in that network or do you need both to be in that network(segment)?

I only need the client app (Vue web app) to be in the same network

"I only need the client app (Vue web app) to be in the same network" - That doesn't make sense to me. The client App runs on the Client (1.1.1.20 in your example). It is hosted through a Server (1.1.1.10 in your example). But that is basically only delivering the executable to the client which then runs that locally. So the Client App actually is calling from 1.1.1.20. The route is not from 20 -> 10 -> backend api. 20 is receiving exec from 10, then executing that and then making a request from 20 -> backend api.

Oh, I see. And yeah i meant the Server and the api need to be in the same network. But it seems that what I want to achieve is not really doable then. I wanted the the request from front to back with the server IP instead of the client IP.

Not all hope is lost. You could still verify that the request has been constructed with the very client that you publish through your Frontend-Host. With certificates you can have authentication in both ways: The Server can prove to the client it is the valid one and vice versa the client can prove to the server that it is an untampered-with client. That's not an outlandish requirement to have.
